# Question about the FARC in the Darién Gap

Tags: central-america, darien-gap

Is there still a FARC presence in the Darién Gap?
Would it be feasible to travel through the region (if one enjoys roughing it)? 
Thanks!

Comment: Even setting aside armed guerrilla groups or lack thereof, it's not simply a matter of whether you "enjoy roughing it." It's [an extremely serious jungle](https://www.outsideonline.com/2098801/skull-stake-darien-gap). This strikes me as one of those "if you have to ask, the answer is no" situations. If you really do the preparation needed for such a trip (which likely includes securing government approvals to do it legally), you'd be able to make your own assessment as to its feasibility.

Comment: By land or by sea?

Comment: FARC is no longer an active guerrila organization having disbanded and laid down its weapons in June 2017. That said, possibility of coming across renegades or a new guerilla organization is still there.

Comment: Isn't the problem rather ordinary criminals than armed political organisations?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments, putting on hold.